# Run server on AT&T android smart phone in 4G mode

Tags: android, sockets, port, firewall

I'm trying to create an app like this -> https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/ The spydroid app works great when on my wifi network. But the problem is when I am in 4G mode. I get an IP like this, 10.132.231 but it seems that I am not allowed to run a server on the phone due to the ports being blocked. Is there anyway I can unblock ports in 4G mode so I can connect to a server running on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

I will first try using ports above 50000, thos are usually unblocked. If that doesn't work, you could try doing the app the other way around, the app connects to a server.

Comment: I tried 50001 and 60000, no luck. Don't think I can run it as the client. It uses rtp, so VLC will connect to the video stream on the phone. But that requires the phone to be the server.